# Calculating proximity in ArcMap 10.6

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity

I am new in Arcmap and I am trying to calculate the distance between some points I have in an excel file that have an FID shape and latitude and longitude. However whichever tool I am trying to open eg. near, proximity I see only an empty grey box and no drop down menu like the tutorials.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other way to calculate the distances?

Comment: Near requires ArcGIS Advanced. See the licensing information at the bottom of the [help pages](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/coverage-toolbox/near.htm) to learn the restrictions for a given tool. At any license level, you could easily script this with Python. Would that be a possibility for you?

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have ArcGIS advanced so maybe I am doing something wrong. I tried both with shp and xls file, but when I open each tool it still has a grey box without the dop down menu. Unfortunately I do not know Python. Is there any other tool I could use?

Comment: Some general thoughts / questions: Have you converted the XLS file to a Shapefile..not an Event Layer? Are the Shapefiles in the same projection, preferably in a projection that is not geographic? Can you post a picture of the tool, perhaps your ArcMap installation is corrupted.